# Android Google plus friend list

Tags: android, google-plus

I having some confusion on google plus friends list ,

Before following (google plus - people method deprecated)

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list

We used following method for getting google plus  friend list,

loadVisiblePeople(...)

but now a day it is deprecated.

So any one tell me , now in a new method of google plus , how to exactly get google friends list and which step follow for the same , and any other gradle file/compile library required for it ?

I study google plus document well but still having same confusion , 
So any one please remove my this confusion.